# (Beta) Site specific chat room creation

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, beta-phase

Noting the lack of a chat link on writers, I set about to see if I could create a room to lurk in regardless, and followed a link which would suggest this is possible:
[image: description]

This brought up what I would expect:
[image: woo create room!]

But rather than create a site specific room by clicking the beautifully circled link, I created [a room on SO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel)

Not *quite* what one would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed this room to be "wrtiters"; I'm now looking to see why it didn't get a room automagically...

(update) This was because the "chat exists" flag was incorrectly set `false` in a few places. This has been corrected. This means the "chat" link now exists, which should make everything automatic.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't create a room on SO's chat server.  On chat.SE, your parent account is by default, the site you have the most rep on.  For you, this is SO.  So when the room was created, it used your parent account and associated the chat room with SO.  You should be able to change this by editing the room info.  If not, pop into the Chat Feedback room and someone can help you.