# How do moderators permanently add Site Chat Room to main page sidebar?

Tags: support, chat, moderator-tools

I noticed in some StackExchange sites that the Chatroom regularly appears in the sidebar.. but in others it does not and though it is on the help menu many users are not even aware it exists as the only link is across the bottom.

How does one permanently add a link to the primary chat rooms to the main side bar like on scifi.stackexchange.com?

> [image]

Playing around it seems there isn't a specific trigger related to it as far as number of users.. unless we simply are not hitting it with 3 and having recent activity.. clicking chat at the bottom of the screen brings up the following:

> [image]

And this is all we see down the side:

> [image]

I searched other questions like but not limited to:

- [(Beta) Site Specific Chat Room Creation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73093/beta-site-specific-chat-room-creation)
- [Should Chat Link to you to a site specific chatroom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68920/should-the-chat-link-of-a-se-2-0-site-take-you-to-the-site-specific-chat-room)
- [What sites should be automatically handled by onebox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/which-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat)
- [How to link to a chatroom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93271/how-to-link-to-a-chat-room)
- [Is it possible to prevent Chat Room from appearing on main sidebar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215264/is-it-possible-to-prevent-a-chat-room-from-appearing-in-the-sidebar-of-a-site)

Comment: Related: [How are the chatrooms shown in the sidebar selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257677/how-are-the-chatrooms-shown-in-the-sidebar-selected) – unfortunately, it has no answer.

Comment: Related: [Show the Chat box in the sidebar for Public Beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127282/show-the-chat-box-in-the-sidebar-for-public-beta-sites) – It seems to be inconsistent across the network?

Answer (score 5):

Moderators don't have a tool to do this, and I don't believe that moderators request that CMs do it.

I'm not sure when, or to whom, the system decides to show rooms in the sidebar.

Comment: If this is correct, does it automatically show up or is there an associated threshold with it showing up?

Comment: @CRSouser I'm less clear on *how* rooms are chosen, but for some reason I want to say the top few (2?) associated with the site are shown based on recent activity.

Comment: They don't show up on M&TV at all... or on Seasoned Advice... Are you certain it's not something that's done manually?

Comment: @Catija It's definitely not done manually by moderators; but I'm failing to find a common denominator among graduated sites that don't have rooms in the sidebar. Of course, this all could have changed since the last time I looked into it.

Comment: It's also possible that it's a CM thing that mods can request... or be related to rep on that site? I have low rep on SFF but higher rep on M&TV and Cooking.

Comment: I've been around for a while, including through a graduation, and I've never once seen a moderator request that of a CM. I'd highly doubt that.

Comment: Never mind... I see them on ELL and that's my highest rep site... it's also very newly graduated...

Comment: @Catija they show only when logged in, and the top two active rooms.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, but I'm not seeing them on [Cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/), for example, even though I'm logged in.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm logged in on **all** of the sites I've mentioned and I only see them on SFF and ELL.

Comment: I'm seeing them on Open Source - that's definitely a beta site

Comment: @Undo I do see it on cooking, though only one site. Can you check browser console for client side errors? The chat widget in sidebar is loaded using JS: `StackExchange.chatAd.init(options);` (you can also view the source and see if something is weird in the options)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nothing in the console.

Comment: @Catija see my comment to Undo - maybe something is borked in the options?

Comment: ... and now it is showing up on M&TV... and Cooking... Maybe someone nudged something? I certainly didn't do anything.

Comment: @Zizouz212 you're probably on the meta site, they do appear on meta of beta sites.

Comment: @Catija weird... maybe worth digging into by a dev, too bad balpha is becoming PM...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I remembered. Chatrooms on Open Source! http://i.stack.imgur.com/eGmnL.png

Comment: @Zizouz212 I think it is a graduated site with the beta design... Will have to look into it bit more though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Open Source isn't graduated, though.